# Write custom function that will happens when throw happened

Tags: c#

Is there a possibility to write a custom function that happened every time that throw of exeption happend without to write try and catch in c#?

**UPDATE**

I Want to get the exeption in my function and I'll check the exeption.
If I write try and catch, the catch will catch the exeption.
But I dont wont that there will be cases that the page will break Because there will not be try and catch.
In such cases I want to go to the base function.

Comment: What exactly would you want this function to do? ie would you want execution to resume from wherever the error is or would you just want to log something before the program dies? A try catch in the Main method of your program would allow you to catch every exception that is thrown but whether that will solve your problem or not is hard to say. Asp.net has similar handlers that you can write methods for that will run on any uncaught exception.

Comment: In general though exception handling shouldn't be general. At any point an exception might be thrown you need to understand the implications of catching it and continuing or whether you should fail. The only time I would really think a general catch all would be useful is when logging things before rethrowing but even then I'd probably wonder if my design was really good if I was doing this without thinking about the specific context.

Answer (score 1):

Either some sort of product like Post Sharp (I think), or something a bit more invasive.  Every call can be wrapped in an anonymous function that handles all exceptions for you.  Then you can do whatever you want in that handler.  Though, this requires you apply that style to all public methods that you'd want to deal with that issue.

Example:

```
public string GetSomeData() {
  return Run(() => { ...some code...  return "my result"; });
}
```

in the Run method, you can handle all try catch or whatever.